# What is the event to do actions while $.post method is in progress jQuery

Tags: ajax, jquery, post, .post

What is the event to do actions while $.post method is in progress jQuery.

Explained more clearly: I use `$.post` method in my code in PHP. I need to display loading image until the `$.post` returns a value!

My code

```
$("#wit").click(function(){
    var story = $("#story").val();
    $.post('diary/ajax/ajax.php', {newdiary:story},function(data){
        if(data=="SORRY")
        {
            alert("Sorry! Try Again in few seconds");
        }
        else
        {

        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just display the loading image in the line before you make your `post()` call.  Then hide the loading image in the callback function.  Note for this sort of operation you should also have a callback for a failed call so that you can hide the image in case the call fails for some reason.